# Adding projections to an nhibernate query

Tags: c#, nhibernate

What would be the best way to add projections to an nhibernate query that already may or may not have 1 or more projections set?  Calling .SetProjection() appears to replace any projections that may already be there.

To give a little background context I am using a version of the paged result extension method found [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/archive/2008/10/03/paging-with-nhibernate-using-a-custom-extension-method-to-make-it-easier.aspx) and I have come to a point where I am passing in a query with a distinct projection already but that projection is stripped for the count criteria because of calling .SetProjection(Projections.RowCountInt64).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it will work, because I can't check it right now, but why don't you use something like a `ProjectionList` to do this trick?

```
var criteria = ...
var projectionList = Projection.ProjectionList();

// Add you projections to the projectionList
projectionList.Add(yourQueryProjection);
projectionList.Add(Projections.RowCountInt64());

criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
```

Comment: It is worth noting that once you choose to use projections that you have to specify every column you want the query to return. My experience with NH is limited but as of yet there doesn't seem to be a way to tell the ICriteria API that you want to select all columns associated with the entity you are selecting and then add one more additional projections to the query... but it doesn't seem like this would be a very difficult extension method to add to a project (or the ICriteria API)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this so you may have to rework it a bit but I believe you can do something like

```
.ProjectionCriteria.Add(Projections.RowCountInt64)
```

Since it may not have any projections set you might want to check what the ProjectionCriteria property is in that case. It may be null.

Comment: I am using an ICriteria so I don't actually have .ProjectionCriteria available to me.  I suppose I could pass in an actual criteria implementation but then I would need an extension method for each ICreiteria implementation.  Any other ideas?